# PHP maketime gives 22.00 the previous day

Tags: php, javascript

I want to create two equal timestamps for a given day in PHP and Javascript, but there's a difference....

1 July 2012:

**PHP**

```
$test = mktime(0,0,0,7,1,2012); gives 1341093600
```

**JavaScript**

```
var d = Date.UTC(2012,6,1); 
var timestamp = d/1000;   gives 1341100800
```

Why the 2 hour difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The call to `Date.UTC` will create a timestamp that is midnight on 2012-07-01 UTC.

[mktime](http://php.net/mktime), on the other hand, will do the same thing except for whatever timezone PHP is configured to use.

In other words, your server isn't set to UTC.

The easiest solution is probably [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime):

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2012-07-01 UTC');
```

There's also [gmmktime](http://php.net/gmmktime) or you could set the timezone of PHP to UTC.  I would do it [in the `.ini`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone), but to do it in code you could use [date_default_timezone_set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php):

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

---

As a note of personal preference, I avoid mktime.  Between `strtotime` and `DateTime`, I very rarely find cases in which mktime results in cleaner, more readable code.  The beastly parameter list of mktime makes any line it's in appear plain frightening.